# How to load the same gltf model in threejs or react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

i'm using react-three-fiber and i want to make a house. So i use a GLTF model for displaying the door.

Render one door is fine but when i render 2 doors from the same GLTF file then only the 2nd door is rendered. Looks like the 2nd door has replaced the 1st instead of being a new door.

How can i achieve having multiple doors, i've searched but there seems to be no one asking this question???

My code:

`Door.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

interface DoorProps {
  rotation: any;
}

function Door(props: DoorProps) {
  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, '/simple_door.gltf');

  return (
    <>
      <primitive
        object={gltf.scene}
        position={[25, 1, -17]}
        scale={0.05}
        rotation={props.rotation}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Door;
```

`Room.tsx`

```
function Room() {
  return (
    <Canvas
      shadows
      dpr={[1, 2]}
      frameloop="demand"
      style={{ height: 800 }}
      camera={{ fov: 75, near: 0.1, far: 1000, position: [0, 10, 20] }}
    >
      <OrbitControls addEventListener={undefined} hasEventListener={undefined} removeEventListener={undefined} dispatchEvent={undefined} />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.8} />
      <color attach="background" args={['#d0d0d0']} />
      <fog attach="fog" args={['#d0d0d0', 100, 600]} />
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Environment preset="city" />
        <Door />
        <Plane 
          width={50}
          height={10}
          depth={1}
          position={[0, 0, -20]}
        />
        <Door
          rotation={[0, 90*Math.PI/180, 0]}
        />

        <Plane 
          width={50}
          height={1}
          depth={50}
          position={[0, -4.5, 5]}
        />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default Room;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to clone your 3D door model,

There are several ways to do so, what you're looking for is probably à simple use of the clone function :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGraph } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'
import { SkeletonUtils } from "three/examples/jsm/utils/SkeletonUtils"

interface DoorProps {
  rotation: any;
}

function Door(props: DoorProps) {
  const { scene, materials, animations } = useGLTF('/simple_door.gltf');
  const clone = useMemo(() => SkeletonUtils.clone(scene), [scene])
  const { nodes } = useGraph(clone)

  return (
    <>
      <primitive
        object={nodes}
        position={[25, 1, -17]}
        scale={0.05}
        rotation={props.rotation}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Door;
```

I used the drei package, because it helps to load other informations than the model if needed

here is another example :
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-wildlife-nrbnq?file=/src/Model.js

you could maybe also want to display a lot of doors, in this case i recommend you to use instancedMesh instead of primitive

also a tool that would help you to create your Door component would be gltfjsx, have a look at it :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltfjsx

Answer (score 1):

you can't add the same model in two places, threejs will unmount it automatically from the first place. the solution is gltfjsx. this is what allows you to re-use models. there is no counterpart for this in vanilla three, and they usually re-parse and/or clone. with gltfjsx the model is loaded and parsed only once, but since it is immutable you can readily re-use it ootb.

here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/re-using-gltfs-dix1y gltfjsx can even generate instances, so no matter how many times you render it, you'll have only one drawcall.

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass `rotation` prop for the first door,

If you don't want to pass `rotation` prop to First Door make the rotation an optional prop like this.

```
interface DoorProps {
   rotation?: any;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But i've tried this and i still can only see the 2nd door, the 1st door with no rotation is not rendered.